# Error reading excel using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel, oledb

In my requirement, I am successfull in opening & reading Excel(both 2003 & 07) data from Asp.net OLEDB.

**But it works only when Excel Sheet Kept open in our PC** , Otherwise it gives 'External Table format error' .What exactly the problem ?.Can anyone show me light please. **Is this anything problem with access rights?**

Am sure Its nothing to do with connection string . My code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string path = @"C:\Users\abcd\Desktop\raj.xls";
            connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + absoluteDir + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;\"";

            OleDbConnection oledbConn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);
            try
            {

                oledbConn.Open();
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", oledbConn);
                OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                oleda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                oleda.Fill(ds);
                GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                // Close connection
                oledbConn.Close();
            } 
        }
```

*Thanks in advance*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with access problem .that mean sheet was password protected.